# How to run delayed_job in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to run delayed job in production (Elastic Beanstalk, AWS) using `$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start`, however I get the following permission error:

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:85:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/app/current/tmp/pids (Errno::EACCES)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:85:in `daemonize'
    from bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

This probably isn't an issue with Delayed Job, but I couldn't really find an answer anywhere to this permission issue and I'm hoping someone might have a clue on what I can do to make it work in production.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather a missing folder, than a permission issue. You should logon to remote using `ssh` and run there:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/app/current/tmp/pids
sudo chmod +xw /var/app/current/tmp/pids
```

In case of feeding the paranoia, one might also `chown` to the user, that actually runs ruby code there, but in this case it is not necessary, since it’s all about storing PIDs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and then tried to run delayed_job again, but with another permission error:

    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:92:in 'initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/app/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid (Errno::EACCES)


Any idea what I can do here, or could you explain how I can use `chown` to solve this? Not much of a command line guy yet!

Comment: You do not need to `chown` in this case. It seems you already have pid files there. Try to run `sudo rm -rf /var/app/current/tmp/pids/*` and restart `delayed_job`. It should help.

Comment: I did your first mkdir command, and then the chown afterwards, and that's what made it work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

1. check which user delay_job start with
2. check `/var/app/current/tmp/pids` permission, the permission must be fit for the user.
3. if `pids` not exists, check `/var/app/current/tmp` permission